# Is there a theme for beamer which looks like Madrid but has squared bloks?

Tags: beamer, themes, block

Iam doing a presentation using `beamer`. I like `Madrid` because it optimizes the space very well, but I prefer the blocks shape of the theme `Berlin`. Is there a theme with those features? Or is there an easy way to customize the shape of the blocks?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use rectangular blocks by using the block template from the default theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
\begin{block}{blabla}
    aerer
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be `\usetheme{Madrid}\useinnertheme{rectangles}`?

Comment: @Ignasi Unfortunately not. That's what I tried first.

Comment: @Ignasi The `rectangles` theme will not overwrite the rounded blocks, because it does not define them itself, but relays on the blocks from the default theme as fall back solution.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you for your investigation